# Minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{5}+\sqrt 2$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, minimal-polynomials

> Find the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{5}+\sqrt{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5})$

*Attempt:*

Let $u:=\sqrt[3]{5}+\sqrt{2}\\
u-\sqrt[3]{5}=\sqrt 2\\
(u-\sqrt[3]{5})^2=2\\
\boxed{u^2-2\sqrt[3]{5}u+5^{2/3}-2=0}$

Is this correct? the "over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5})$" confuses me

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. For simplicity, set $a=\sqrt[3]{5}$. Then $u=a+\sqrt{2}$ becomes
$$
u-a=\sqrt{2}
$$
so
$$
u^2-2au+a^2=2
$$
and the element $u$ is a root of $X^2-2aX+a^2-2$ which is a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}(a)$.

However, you should prove also that $u=a+\sqrt{2}\notin\mathbb{Q}(a)$, which is equivalent to $\sqrt{2}\notin\mathbb{Q}(a)$.

This can be tackled by considering that $[\mathbb{Q}(a):\mathbb{Q}]=3$, so the field $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ cannot contain a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.